# Difficulty sending media from my phone through whatsapp

Tags: whatsapp

There are some videos and songs but I can't send them through WhatsApp because when I tab on them to send the WhatsApp application doesn't show so what can I do?

Comment: check the file size.

Answer (score 1):

You can send video and songs. But only one by one.

For video, go to whatsapp and attach video files one by one to the sender.

For songs, install an app like 'Files' and go to the location of the song file and change its extension to '.mp4' (i.e. as a video file) and save it in the video folder. Then go to whatsapp and attach video file, there you can see the song. Send it, it'll be received as a song.